# How to transform this "Select" into a Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, sql, lambda

Does anyone know how to transform the following "select" into a lambda expression?

`SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE OID IN (SELECT OIDPhone FROM table2 WHERE city = 'New York')`

Comment: yes. what effort have you made?

Comment: I have tried a lot of different things and nothing worked. Instead of publishing different ways to do something wrong I decided to ask for a simple help. And you could be more helpfull just like Mr.Habib was or simply have not answered if you do not know the solution. Thank you Mr. Habib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
var subQuery = db.OIDPhone.Where(r=> r.City == "New York").Select(r=> r.OIDPhone);
var finalQuery = db.Table1.Where(r=> subQuery.Contains(r.OID));
```